# Why doesn't IPython.display.Audio() work when in a for cycle?

Tags: python, ipython

I have a problem that I can not find the solution of. I am coding a synthesizer. When I want to use `dis.Audio()` from `import IPython.display as dis` as a way of hearing what I have done mathematically it doesn't output the .wav file that should be. A piece of the code ( for the current test ) is:

```py
FREQ_d = 523
SAMPLES_RATE = 40000
t_samples = np.linspace(0, 4, 4*SAMPLES_RATE)

for j in song.values():
    if j['note'] == 'd':
        dis.Audio(np.sin(2*np.pi*FREQ_d*t_samples), rate=SAMPLES_RATE)
```

There is no problem with the if. I have made sure of that. When I try writting something like this:

```py
SAMPLES_RATE = 40000
t_samples = np.linspace(0, 4, 4*SAMPLES_RATE)
freq1 = 200
freq2 = 201
s1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*freq1*t_samples)
s2 = np.sin(2*np.pi*freq2*t_samples)
s = s1 + s2
dis.Audio(s, rate=SAMPLES_RATE)
```

There is no problem and it outputs the audio.

I don't know the cause of the problem in the first chunk of code. Sorry if it is hard to understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You should call it that way when you want to display it inside loop:

```
...
for i in range(100):
    dis.display(dis.Audio(...))
...
```